# Is Viscosity due to adhesive forces or cohesive?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, viscosity, adhesion

So if a non-ideal fluid is in motion, in a siphon for instance, then I completely understand why viscosity could arise due to cohesive forces between the particles.

But let's say we drop a metal sphere in a container full of this non-ideal fluid, then viscosity acts on the metal surface too right? So in this example, shouldn't viscosity also arise due to adhesive forces?

Comment: Are you familiar with the non-slip boundary condition?

Comment: @ChetMiller I googled it and so I understood the basics